# Sorting column based on number of occurences in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset which has a column named 'customername'.

Sample dataset:

```
+==================================+===============+==+==+===============================+==+
 |          Customer Name           | Customer code |  |  |         Invoice Type          |  |
+==================================+===============+==+==+===============================+==+
 | ALECTRONA ENERGY PRIVATE LIMITED | IMA281        |  |  | In-Bonding Invoice            |  |
+----------------------------------+---------------+--+--+-------------------------------+--+
| A P SRINIVASAN AND SONS          | CHA061        |  |  | In-Bonding Invoice            |  |
+----------------------------------+---------------+--+--+-------------------------------+--+
| MOLEX INDIA PVT LTD              | IMM098        |  |  | Import Final Delivery Invoice |  |
+----------------------------------+---------------+--+--+-------------------------------+--+
```

Required: 
Based on frequency I need to sort the dataset. Ex. If I have name as 'Hogg' it needs to print how many times 'hogg" occured and sort the whole dataset which has maximum occurence.
For this I used below command,

```
arrangedone = sort(table(data$`Customer Name`),decreasing = TRUE)
```

Which gives customer name with max appearance, based on this I need to sort the whole dataset.
And I arranged or sorted by using arrange command.

```
arrange(data,arrangedone).
```

It throws an error as

```
     "Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots):incorrect size (2243) at position 1, expecting : 28898
```

Can I have any other option/command to overcome this?

Thanks

Comment: Can't find "Hogg" in your sample dataset. Can you add `dput` of your dataframe and add an expected output for the same?

Comment: "Hogg" is just the example but I have multiple rows which I cannot post it..

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to sort a dataset using a variable, and display how many occurrences there were you may want to try the `add_count()` function from the `dplyr` package. I have created a small reproducible example below to demonstrate. Using the sort = TRUE parameter will sort the data set based on the count of occurrences.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

custs <- tibble::tribble(
  ~customername, ~customercode,
          "Bob",         1234L,
         "Jane",         4567L,
        "Alice",         5487L,
      "Michael",         7891L,
          "Bob",         1234L,
         "Jane",         4567L,
      "Michael",         7891L,
          "Bob",         1234L
  )

custs %>% 
  add_count(customername, sort = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   customername customercode     n
#>   <chr>               <int> <int>
#> 1 Bob                  1234     3
#> 2 Bob                  1234     3
#> 3 Bob                  1234     3
#> 4 Jane                 4567     2
#> 5 Michael              7891     2
#> 6 Jane                 4567     2
#> 7 Michael              7891     2
#> 8 Alice                5487     1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>